# Unexpected TikZ ifthenelse behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

The Ti*k*Z user guide (version 3.18b, page 1042) says this:

> `ifthenelse(x,y,z)` This returns y if x evaluates to some non-zero value, otherwise z is returned.

It would appear that **both** `y` **and** `z` are *first evaluated* and **then** returned, which is (to me) a surprise; a TeX `\if` does not evaluate the *unused* option -- so why does Ti*k*Z bother to evaluate an *unused* option? I discovered this in a vain attempt to avoid division by zero:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\foo}{0}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\foobar}{ifthenelse(equal(\foo,0),0,1)}\foobar

%% Both return the error: "You've asked me to divide `1' by `0'..."
% Uncomment the following to see the problem:
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\foobar}{ifthenelse(equal(\foo,0),0,1/\foo)}\foobar
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\foobar}{ifthenelse(greater(\foo,0),1/\foo,0)}\foobar

\end{document}
```

There are a number of non-Ti*k*Z approaches (for the moment I have settled on `\ifdim\foo pt=0...\else...\fi`). Just wondering what a more Ti*k*Z-idiomatic approach might be.

Comment: It works perfectly here. Probably something is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Did you *un*comment the second two instances of `\pgfmathsetmacro{\foo}...`? They do not work.

Comment: Yes, both work in latest PGF (TeX Live 2020). It's `1.0` in both

Comment: By bad. The problem occurs with `\pgfmathsetmacro{\foo}{0}` -- I posted, in error, an interim version of the file. Changed in code. Apologies. And, yes, using MacTeX2020.

Comment: As I just checked in the code, the question/answer from 2015 still applies. It is simply the way the expression evaluator of `pgf` works. `ifthenelse` is a function with three arguments, and pgf evaluates the arguments first before applying the function to the values.

Comment: I did search existing questions and did not find that 2015 answer. Thanks. Looks like that's just the way it is.

Comment: @gernot I did try that, but if \foo happens to be a non-integer, then `\ifnum` gives an error: `Missing number, treated as zero.`

Comment: @gernot Yes, as I pointed out in my question, I use the (seems kludgy to me) `\ifdim\foo pt=0...\else...\fi` trick

Comment: Ah, sorry. It seems you have already found the best solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't poke the dancing bear.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\foo}{0}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\foobar}{ifthenelse(equal(\foo,0),0,1/ifthenelse(equal(\foo,0),1,\foo))}\foobar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Same error, for the same reason: the arguments are evaluated first.

Comment: Just tried it -- right, same error.

Comment: So, does this answer the question?

Comment: Sorry, I put the arguments in the wrong order.